# How can I add an object to an array if object name is from another array?

Tags: javascript

```
var streamerStatus = [];

var streamers = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++){

streamerStatus.push({streamers[i]: 'OFFLINE'});

}
```

Comment: ES6: `streamerStatus.push({[streamers[i]]: 'OFFLINE'})`

Comment: ES6: `streamerStatus = streamers.map( k => ({ [k] : 'OFFLINE' }) )`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++){
  var obj = {};
  obj[streamers[i]] = 'OFFLINE';

  streamerStatus.push(obj);
}
```